# How to get from a BulkItemResponse to corresponding Request

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

I'm using [Elasticsearch's bulk requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-bulk.html) in Java and I'm trying to handle the situations where some error happens:

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get();
if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
    for (BulkItemResponse response : bulkResponse) {
        if (response.isFailed()
        || response.getResponse().getShardInfo().getFailed() > 0) {
            //Find the corresponding request and resend it
        }
    }
}
```

After finding the response with error, I want to re-send its request since in my case errors could be momentary and in most of the cases a retry could resolve the problem.

So my question is, how to get from `BulkItemResponse` to the original `Request` that led it? Is there any way better than relying on the order of requests and responses?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have that AFAIK. You need somehow to keep all elements you added to a bulk and in case of error use the id coming from `response.getId()` to associate that with the original data.

So something similar to:

```
HashMap<String, Object> myData = new HashMap<>();

BulkRequestBuilder brb = BulkAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);

myData.put(myObject.getId(), myObject);
brb.add(new IndexRequest("index", "type", myObject.getId()).source(myObject.toJson()));

// Other actions
BulkResponse response = client.bulk(brb.request()).get();
response.forEach(bulkItemResponse -> {
    if (bulkItemResponse.isFailed()) {
        Object objectToSendAgain = myData.get(bulkItemResponse.getId());
        // Do what is needed with this object
    }
});

myData = null;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are assuming that within each `BulkRequestBuilder` the `myObject.getId()` is unique but that's not necessarily true. I might have one insert and one update / delete in one bulk request for the same document.

Comment: Update the map in that case.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean! Consider a scenario where in the same bulk two requests share the same id and one of them fails. How your solution handles this situation? I believe relying on id will never do.

Comment: You can use a linkedHashMap which preserves the order may be?

Comment: That was my original proposition, using the order. I was wondering if there's any other way than using the order of requests!

Comment: I don't see any other. For sure you have to maintain a list of requests in your code.